# Replacing slice by an iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice

I have a list `s` which looks as below:

```
s = [1, 2, 3]
```

I am replacing `slice of 's'` using below code:

```
s[1:4] = [22, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
print(s)
```

**Output:** `[1, 22, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

My understanding `s[1:4]` should replace only `3 elements` `starting from 1st element` and `up to but not including 4th element.`

**Assumed Output:** `[1, 22, 3, 4]`

Comment: And your understanding is exactly what is happening, so where exactly do you see a problem? You know that indexing starts at `0`, right? Also, any slice that goes over the end of the list stops at the end. So, as expected, 2 and 3 get replaced by 22 and so on.

Comment: if `s = [1,2,3]` then `s[1]` returns `2` since python uses 0-indexed lists

Comment: In order to get the functionality that it sounds like you desire, you would have to do something like `b,e=1,4; s[b:e] = [22,3,4,5,6,7][0:(e-b)]` (provided `e >= b`)

Comment: "My understanding s[1:4] should replace only 3 elements " that is not correct. The number of elements replaced is **not determined by the size of the slice** but by the iterable you are using in the slice-assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So let's use a better example. I've included the output as commented out code in the code snippets

```
s = list(range(1, 11))
print(f"Len = {len(s)} | S = {s}")

# Len = 10 | S = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

#### There are 3 scenarios:

##### Case 1: Assigned list is shorter than the index range

```
s = list(range(1, 11))
s[1:4] = [0, 0]
print(f"Len = {len(s)} | S = {s}")

# Len = 9 | S = [1, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

**Ans :** The list size is shrunk by 1 since only 2 items are being assigned to 3 places.

##### Case 2: Assigned list is longer than the index range

```
s = list(range(1, 11))
s[1:4] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
print(f"Len = {len(s)} | S = {s}")

# Len = 14 | S = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

**Ans :** The list size is increased by 4 since 7 items are being assigned to 3 places.

##### Case 3: Assigned list is equal to index range

```
s = list(range(1, 11))
s[1:4] = [0, 0, 0]
print(f"Len = {len(s)} | S = {s}")

# Len = 10 | S = [1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

**Ans :** In this case it will be replaced properly since both the sizes match.

#### Conclusion

- Python seems to be shrinking and growing the list to accommodate the assigned items.
- All elements outside the slice indices will not be affected regardless of how big/small the assigned list is.

---

##### Update

As @mealhour pointed out there is a fourth case where you can increase the step size to be greater than 1 and assign it to every kth item in the list. In this case, the sizes have to match otherwise, python throws an error. This [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47968232/why-is-extended-slice-assignment-less-flexible-than-regular-slice-assignment) explains it really well

```
s = list(range(1, 11))
# s[1:4:2] = [0, 0, 0] <- This throws an error
s[1:4:2] = [0, 0]
print(f"Len = {len(s)} | S = {s}")

# Len = 10 | S = [1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Why are you using `np.arange` here? just change it to `range`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I wasn't aware you could convert the `range()` generator into a list. Nice to know :) I have updated my answer

Comment: @DollarAkshay of course you can. Note, you can convert *any* iterable to a list, generators are iterable. But also note, `range` is not a generator

Comment: @DollarAkshay thanks for the insights. can you please also provide case example on how `assignment to extended slice` works?  How `s[1:4:2] = [0, 0, 0]` will work?

Comment: @DollarAkshay thanks again. I have also created another question for it and want to request you to please help answer it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71550868/replacing-extended-slice-of-a-list-with-another-list?noredirect=1#comment126459337_71550868

Answer (score 1):

```
s = [1,2,3]
x = [22,3,4,5,6]
j = 0
for i in range(1,4):
    try:
        s[i] = x[j]
    except IndexError:
        s.append(x[j])
    j +=1
```

You can use something like this to achieve your goal

Comment: `s[1:4] = [22, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7][:3]` will also do the trick