# Replacing extended slice of a list with another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice

I have a list `s` which looks as below:

```
s = list(range(1, 11))
```

I am replacing `slice of 's'` using below code:

```
s[1:4] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
print(s)
```

**Output:** `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

However, when trying to assign the same list `[0, 0, 0, 0]` to an `extended slice of 's'`, then the interpreter is throwing an error.

```
s[1:4:2] = [0, 0, 0, 0]

ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 4 to extended slice of size 2
```

I want to understand why python didn't throw an error with `s[1:4] = [0, 0, 0, 0]` because even in that case we are attempting to assign sequence of size 4 to slice of size 3?

Comment: What is the expected result with using the slice option `[1:4:2]` ?

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what's wrong: `s[1:4:2]` is equivalent to `[2, 4]`. How can you assign `[0, 0, 0, 0]` to those two spots?

Comment: I have updated my question. please have a look. thanks!

Comment: If you look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=cached_property#sequence-types-list-tuple-range): `s[i:j:k] = t` means _the elements of `s[i:j:k]` are replaced by those of t_, and _t must have the same length as the slice it is replacing_. There's no length requirement in the case of `s[i:j] = t`: _slice of s from i to j is replaced by the contents of the iterable t_.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to understand why python didn't throw an error with s[1:4] = [0, 0, 0, 0] because even in that case we are attempting to assign sequence of size 4 to slice of size 3?

Let's even take a more "hardcore example"

```
s = list(range(1, 11))
s[1:2] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
print(s)
```

What is exactly done here is:

1. Take s[1:2] elements, in this case it's only the value 2.
2. Place elements into this spot, as in replace values between index 1 and 2 with corresponding values.

While you are trying to apply it to s[1:4:2] so values 2 and 4, you are trying to do what you were saying, as in:

> Assign sequence of size 4 to slice of size 3

Which clearly can't be done.
Also, coming back to the first example, check also the same thing with s[1:1], s[1] and you will find funny examples of this thing.